# Is having a lot of threads in an application counter productive?

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, qt, qthread

I'm currently trying to implement a multithreaded database connection interface for personal use. This is implemented using 3 classes

- `DatabaseManager` A database connexion instancier instantiating a new thread for each connection
- `Database` an object inheriting from QThread, meant to be run in the main thread and exposing an interface to do things on a worker object
- `DatabaseWorker` the worker object that runs an event loop in a worker thread managing a single database connection, awaits queries and deliver results through Qt:QueuedConnections (signal/slots)
- When a connection is no longer used (explicit call to a `close()` method), it's related event loop is stopped and the thread is deleted. The purpose of that is to keep thread creation and deletion at a minimum.

this architecture have a lot of success so far with a limited number of threads (less than 10 connections usually). My main problem is that I don't know how it will behave if I have 100+ connections which mean 100+ threads for one application which bring my main question

Is having a lot of thread in an application counter productive? what happens if I open 50/100/500/1000 connections at the same time? if I do that, I/O database operations are going to take a lot of time to complete (it has not been designed for that in a first place) but how much of that lag is caused by the number of threads?

Comment: That depends on the hardware that runs the application. If you can actually run the threads on different cores, then you'll have a gain as long as the scheduler doesn't choke each individual core. That's with the usual caveat of the thread jobs really being independent. There's no definite answer here, only profiling can tell.

Comment: Dunno - ask your database:)   100, or even 1000, threads is not in itself, a particular problem.  The characteristics of your DB might be..

Comment: The hardware is an Intel I5 2.4GHz with 6 hardware threads and opening a lot of connections to databases is not a problem since I can open 100 connections to 100 different databases on different severs. I'm only concerned about my local application for now

Comment: Yeah... the thing is, it depends on you rDB interface.  If every DB call is fully locked up with a mutex, it doesn't matter whether you have 1 core or 64:(

Comment: With a thread per connection approach, once you hit about 800 connections, you start to see significant performance problems if you have to do a little bit of work for each of a large number of connections.

Comment: What kind of database are you talking about? And what kind of queries? You may end up with competition on the database side!

Comment: it's not a problem for me. I can have 100 connections to 100 different databases, multiple connections to the same database are possible but throw a warning because of that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number of threads in of itself is not a huge problem. Each one uses some memory but for modern machines that overhead is not huge.

The main problem comes when all those threads start trying to do work at once, they start fighting for resources and you can end up with a slower result than you get from a smaller number of threads working smarter.

A thread pool is a common solution for this sort of situation, where tasks get queued up to be performed and you have a thread pool with a suitable number of threads for your machine (for example one thread per core) that processes items off the queue. If your threads spend a lot of time idle waiting for responses then more threads might be warranted, if they are constantly doing calculations though then adding more might well actually slow things down.

Measure the performance and adjust accordingly :) "Gut feel" is very unreliable when working on performance.

Comment: I concur. Some people hate threads, but if you use a thread pool you avoid too many threads while still getting application logic similar to the 'one thread per connection' model. When writing socket code, I really hate having to return with half-read data on a socket and do a lot of ugly book-keeping. Threads, or in some cases, coroutines, allow for much cleaner code, which also translates to fewer bugs. Debugging threaded apps can be a pain, though...

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that yes, it's counter productive. Each thread uses up a significant chunk of memory for its stack space and if you only have 6 cores you cannot run 100s of threads in parallel anyways. Use a thread pool instead, e.g. via KF5 ThreadWeaver or Qt Concurrent and pay attention to the ideal thread count.

Comment: Well ideal thread count is relevant for CPU-heavy operation. database access are blocking IO operation. If I had exactly 6 threads, my application would be sleeping 80% of the time awaiting for responses from a server. I definitely need more than that

Comment: both ThreadWeaver and Qt Concurrent allow you to tune the number of threads in a pool. Use profiling to find an optimal value for your use-case, The ideal thread count is a safe first bet, certainly better than leaving it unbound and spinning up hundreds of potentially temporary threads.